# Can't find httpd.conf on Ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, httpd.conf

I have installed apache and going to configure the apache settings in Ubuntu 12.10, but I can't find the httpd.conf file (I have searched for it, but it seems I don't have the file in my system).

Can I create the file (will that work) or is there another solution?

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu the main configuration file is

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

However it's also split out into different files that can be found in

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled
```

There are also

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
/etc/apache2/mods-available
```

You should probably spend some time reading the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/httpd.html) to get an idea how Ubuntu organises the apache configuration.

Comment: i cant find my /etc/apache2 directory

Answer (score 4):

You need to be looking in **/etc/apache2** for Apache configuration on Ubuntu.

config is spread over a few files. Including **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** and **/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**

Virtual Host definitions should be placed in /etc/apache2/sites-available/sitename.conf and turned on/off with

```
a2ensite sitename.conf
a2dissite sitename.conf
```

You may find the Ubuntu community apache documentation helpful: [Ubuntu community apache info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Andy

Comment: I have looked in /etc/apache2 but the only .conf files in there is apache2.conf and ports.conf. Sigurd

Comment: httpd.conf has nothing mandatory.

Comment: I am trying to install a software, and the installation instruction tells me to incude some lines in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: If you feel safer putting them there, do. BUT, ensure your apache2.conf file contains a `Include httpd.conf` directive.